# Where to download the latest ubuntu touch iso?

Tags: uefi, windows, ubuntu-touch, iso, tablet

Im looking for the iso/img of ubuntu-touch as im planning to install it on my windows tablet. I have already searched here and on google and most of the links were dead. I already have the BOOTIA64.EFI and managed to install ubuntu 16.04 successfully.

I know that the [15.04 img is public](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/vivid/daily-preinstalled/current/), but i think that is not the latest version as [theres an archive (404) of a 17.04 version](https://web.archive.org/web/20180409173441/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/), and there could be an even more recent version.

My tablet is x64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Try the ubuntu touch official web page

https://ubuntu-touch.io/es/get-ubuntu-touch